# Leaflet JS - center and zoom on feature group

Tags: javascript, leaflet

### Code:

```
var map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/41339be4c5064686b781a5a00678de62/998/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{minZoom:8, maxZoom:15}).addTo(map);

marker1 = L.marker([37.4185539, -122.0829068]).addTo(map);
marker1.bindPopup("Google Campus");
marker2 = L.marker([37.792359, -122.404686]).addTo(map);
marker2.bindPopup("Financial District");
var group = new L.featureGroup([marker1, marker2]);
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

The above code will center the map on the center of the markers, but does not set a zoom level so that the markers and only the markers are visible.

If I leave out the 'minZoom' attribute of the map object when adding the initial layer, the entire globe is visible. **My desire is to have the map set a zoom and boundaries so that the markers are visible, and zoomed in.** Any clues on how to accomplish this?
I thought that the fitBounds method would set a Zoom level, but for some reason in my situation it does not do so.

Comment: Your code works very well as expected with Leaflet 0.7.1. http://jsfiddle.net/uVKUL/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is setting the map to a zoom level where both of the markers are visible at the highest possible zoom level. Because of the distance between the two markers and [the way web mapping works](http://macwright.org/mapschool/), this is best fit using raster map tiles. Higher zoom levels will be zoomed in so much that you won't be able to see both markers.